# Расширение меню в зависимости от контента

Tags: html, css

Собственно прошу помощи. Есть контент у которого бывает разная высота, и есть меню. Как сделать что бы меню расширялось в зависимости от контента? Тоесть меню с фиксированной минимальной высотой, но если контент больше минимальной высоты меню, то расширить меню до высоты контента. Желательно на css (если что пишу я на ангуляре 6).
[image: Илюстрация]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать так:

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 500px; //та сама минимальная высота для меню
  position: relative;
}
.menu-blk {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
}

.content-blk {
  margin-left: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu-blk">
  </div>
  
  <div class="content-blk">
  </div>
</div>
```

Другой вариант - использовать flex:

Родительскому контейнеру задать свойство `display: flex;`, тогда все дочерние элементы будут растягиваться по умолчанию на всю высоту родителя, и если один дочерний больше других то и они под него подстраиваются